# Delete Selection Mode - Enter

Tags: delete-selection-mode

How can I have `delete-selection-mode` work when I press Enter (`RET`) in Org mode? I can always just delete the selection and then use `RET`, but I'm having a hard time working this into my muscle memory.

Current behavior: I select the text I want to replace. I use `RET`. A newline is input at point, no text is deleted, and the region remains active.

Desired behavior: I select the text I want to replace. I use `RET`. The text is replaced with a newline.

FINAL EDIT: This was an issue with the version of Org mode that I had installed. I was able to resolve it by opening Emacs and immediately (before opening any .org files) `package-list-packages` and installing `org`. I had to restart Emacs, and the issue was resolved.

Comment: When I set `delete-selection-mode` to `t`, I get the desired behavior you describe.

Comment: What @aadcg said. Do you see the same problem if you start Emacs with `emacs -Q`? If not, bisect your init file to find the culprit. Also, if you see the problem only in some specific mode or context, provide a step-by-step recipe to repro the problem, starting with `emacs -Q`

Comment: This can happen in a mode that configures Enter to do something other than just insert a newline and possibly indent. What mode is it (i.e. what file type are you editing)? What is RET bound to (`C-h c RET`)?

Comment: The problem indeed existed, but it has been fixed upstream, and is currently already part of the latest release. Can you report what you get from `M-x org-version` ?

Comment: Thanks for the help with this.

Answer (score 1):

This problem was solved in the last version of Org mode by adding the following line:

```el
(put 'org-return 'delete-selection t)
```